# The meaning of んや

Tags: words, sentence-final-particles, kansai-ben

Here are two examples that I have encountered ん＋や

> ずっと変｛へん｝な夢｛ゆめ｝を見｛み｝とったような気｛き｝がする**んや**けど・・・

another example:

> なんか、体調｛たいちょう｝悪｛わる｝い**んや**ない？

I am still trying to have a better sense of the letters that add up individually to the end of the sentences in Japanese language, such as ね、ん、さ、や. So in this case, my question is:

Is there any particular situation in which や　is being commonly used after ん　and if so, what sort of expression it conveys? or we must always try to understand them separately?

Comment: Did you encounter this in the kansai area?

Comment: @ajsmart I don't know. This is from an anime I am working on now, 君の名は。is the name of the anime. But if that is the case, it would be interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am fairly certain that what you encountered is actually part of 関西弁｛かんさいべん｝, or the regional dialect in Kansai.  Sometimes Kansai dialect is used to add a different feeling to a character.  Sometimes it is to add humor (especially when foreigners use it), but it really depends on the context in which it is used.

[や is an element of 関西弁](https://www.nihongoresources.com/language/dialects/kansaiben.html) that will replace だ at the end of a sentence. (Third listed item in the link attached.)  You will hear it commonly used in the following ways.

> Kansai: （そう/せぇ）**や**（ね/な）。
> Normally: そう**だ**ね。
>
> Kansai:　そうなん**や**。
> Normally: そうなん**だ**。
>
> Kansai:　…**や**けど。
> Normally: …**だ**けど。

You will find that the past tense form of や is やった.

やない is the Kansai form of じゃない, as the link I included states.

---

The ん that you encountered is actually the contracted form of の from the grammar principle [のです/んだ](http://maggiesensei.com/2010/09/08/request-lesson-when-and-how-to-use-%E3%82%93n-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E2%86%92%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%EF%BC%89/).